# Erro na requisição Ajax

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

Eu preciso enviar o valor de uma tabela que está em um modal para o servidor e logo depois abrir um outro modal usando as informações da primeira tabela, porém a variável sempre me retorna nula, já tentei usar ajax porém não funcionou, ele não faz nada e não me passa nenhum feedback, segue os código para melhor compreensão do problema:

MODAL QUE PASSA A INFORMAÇÃO:

```
<form id="visualizarAparelhos" name="visualizarAparelhos" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <table class="table table">
      <thead> 
        <tr>
        <th>Número</th>
        <th>Nome</th>
        <tbody>
          <?php
            $con = mysqli_connect("localhost","roberto","","manutencao");
            $query = ("select max(id) from aparelhos");
            $max = mysqli_query($con,$query);
            $fetch = mysqli_fetch_row($max);
            $max = $fetch[0];
            $i = 0;
              while ($i != $max)
              {
                $i++;
                $con = mysqli_connect("localhost","roberto","","manutencao");
                $query = ("select id,nome from aparelhos where id = ".$i." ");
                $aparelho = mysqli_query($con,$query);
                $fetch = mysqli_fetch_row($aparelho);
                $id = $fetch[0];
                $nome = $fetch[1];
                print "<tr>";
                // PRECISO PASSAR O IdAparelho para o segundo modal
                  print "<td id='IdAparelho' value='".$id."'><button type='button' class='btn btn-primary' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#modalVisualizarComponentes'>".$id."</button></td>"; 
                  print "<td><strong>".$nome."</strong></td>";
                print "</tr>";
              }
          ?>
        </tbody>   
        </tr>
      </thead>   
    </table>
    </form>
```

MODAL QUE RECEBE A INFORMAÇÃO:

```
<div class="modal-body">
    <table class="table table-striped">
        <tr>
        <th>Sequencial</th>
        <th>Código</th>
        <th>Nome</th>
        <th>Entrada</th>
        <th>Saída</th>
        <th>Quantidade F</th>
        <th>Quantidade M</th>
        <th>Quantidade G</th>
        <th>Quantidade GG</th>
        <th>Total</th>
        <tbody>
          <?php
            $con = mysqli_connect("localhost","roberto","","manutencao");
            // VOU USAR A INFORMAÇÃO DO OUTRO MODAL AQUI
            $query = ("select id_principal from componentes where id_secundario = ".$_POST['IdAparelho']." ");
            $ids = mysqli_query($con,$query);
            while ($linha = mysqli_fetch_array($ids))
            {
                $con = mysqli_connect("localhost","roberto","","manutencao");
                $query = ("select * from componentes where id_principal = ".$linha[0]." ");
                $componentes = mysqli_query($con,$query);
                $resultado = mysqli_fetch_row($componentes);

                $id_componente = $resultado[1];
                $codigo = $resultado[2];
                $nome = $resultado[3];
                $entrada = $resultado[4];
                $saida = $resultado[5];
                $f = $resultado[6];
                $m = $resultado[7];
                $g = $resultado[8];
                $gg = $resultado[9];
                $total = ($f + $m + $g + $gg);

                print "<tr>";
                  print "<td><strong>".$id_componente."</strong></td>";
                  print "<td><strong>".$codigo."</strong></td>";
                  print "<td><strong>".$nome."</strong></td>";
                  print "<td><strong>".$entrada."</strong></td>";
                  print "<td><strong>".$saida."</strong></td>";
                  print "<td><strong>".$f."</strong></td>";
                  print "<td><strong>".$m."</strong></td>";
                  print "<td><strong>".$g."</strong></td>";
                  print "<td><strong>".$gg."</strong></td>";
                  print "<td><strong>".$total."</strong></td>";
                print "</tr>";
              }
          ?>
        </tbody>   
        </tr>
      </thead>   
    </table>    
  </div>
```

O MEU AJAX:

```
 $(function () {    
        $("#visualizarAparelhos").submit(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var FormData = $($this).serialize(); 
            $.ajax({
              type: "POST", 
              url: "administrador.php",
              data: FormData
            }).done(function (data) {
                alert(data);
            });
        return false;
        alert("Não funfou!!!");
        }); 
    });
```

Comment: adminstrador.php está recebendo o IdAparelho?

Comment: Ahamm, no caso a mesma página php que está enviando, é a que vai receber.

Comment: Cai sempre no **success**? Já tentou implementar o **error** no seu código Ajax e inspecionar se algum erro está acontecendo?

Comment: Editei o meu ajax, e agora sempre cai no done, botei para mostrar o alert do meu data, porém não mostra o IdAparelho no alert, acho que não está enviando justamente a informação que eu preciso.

Comment: Serialize pega dados de uma tabela? Até onde sei somente de inputs...

Comment: nesse caso eu usaria então?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neste caso como é uma tabela, não dá para serializar.
Se você precisa passar apenas o ID, podes fazer assim:

```
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST", 
            url: "administrador.php",
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {IdAparelho: $('#IdAparelho').val()}
        }).done(function (data) {
            alert(data);
        });
```

Comment: Fiz dessa forma, só porque nunca cai no alert, simplesmente não faz nada e no log não tem nenhum erro.

Comment: Mudei dataType de json para html, e funcionou valeuuu